# Get result automatically when entering an input number and choosing from dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update a field based on the number the user enters in an input field and on the option he chooses from a dropdown menu. It worked before just with the input field but can't make it work mixed with the dropdown menu.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon border-grey">Enter Price</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" name="enterprice" id="enterprice">
</div><br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon border-grey">Choose Rate</span>
  <select class="form-control" id="chooserate" name="chooserate">
    <option value="0"> - </option>
    <option value="1">1st option</option>
    <option value="2">2nd option</option>
    <option value="3">3rd option</option>
  </select>
</div><br><br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon border-grey">Result</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" name="result" id="result" readonly>
</div>
```

And the js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enterprice, #chooserate").on("input, option", function() {
      if (parseInt($("#chooserate").val()) == 2) {
        var rate = '.$phpnum.'/3;
      } else if (parseInt($("#chooserate").val()) == 3) {
        var rate = '.$phpnum.'/6;
      } else {
        var rate = 1;
      }
      var price = parseInt($("#enterprice").val());
      var total = price * rate;
      $("#result").val(Intl.NumberFormat('el-GR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(total));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
.on("input, option", function() {
```

The first parameter of the `.on()` method is an event. Here `input` is a valid event, but `option` is not. Before you added the select tag, you probably had only:

```
.on("input", function() {
```

And it was working because the `input` event fires when you type into the input field, but it has nothing to do with the name of the tag. In fact the `input` event will also fire when interacting with the select tag, so you just need to remove `, option`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enterprice, #chooserate").on("input", function() {
      if (parseInt($("#chooserate").val()) == 2) {
        var rate = '.$phpnum.'/3;
      } else if (parseInt($("#chooserate").val()) == 3) {
        var rate = '.$phpnum.'/6;
      } else {
        var rate = 1;
      }
      var price = parseInt($("#enterprice").val());
      var total = price * rate;
      $("#result").val(Intl.NumberFormat('el-GR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(total));
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon border-grey">Enter Price</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" name="enterprice" id="enterprice">
</div><br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon border-grey">Choose Rate</span>
  <select class="form-control" id="chooserate" name="chooserate">
    <option value="0"> - </option>
    <option value="1">1st option</option>
    <option value="2">2nd option</option>
    <option value="3">3rd option</option>
  </select>
</div><br><br>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon border-grey">Result</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="5" name="result" id="result" readonly>
</div>
```